# How to effectively load and process JSON files containing different, evolving schemas

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a complex data issue that for the sake of argument cannot be modified. Here is a dummy example JSON file from a database dump:

```
{"payload": {"table": "Table1", "data": {"colA": 1, "colB": 2}}}
{"payload": {"table": "Table2", "data": {"colA": 1, "colC": 2}}}
```

So I have in each file in the directory data from multiple tables each with their own schema. The schema can change over time as columns are added upstream, so we can't define a static schema and are relying on schema inference.

This is my current workflow (high-level):

- Load entire directory of JSON data into one dataframe
- Find unique tables present in this batch of changes
- For each table, filter dataframe down to just that tables data
- Read the schema for the table subset (Table1 is A+B, Table2 is A+C)
- Do some validation
- Merge records with destination

Example code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.read.text(directory)
with_table_df = (
    df
    .withColumn("table", F.get_json_object('value', '$.payload.table'))
    .withColumn("json_payload_data", F.get_json_object('value', '$.payload.data'))
)
unique_tables = with_table_df.select('table').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()

for table in unique_tables:
    filtered_df = with_table_df.filter(f"table = '{table}'")
    table_schema = spark.read.json(filtered_df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.json_payload_data)).schema

    changes_df = (
        filtered_df
        .withColumn('payload_data', F.from_json('json_payload_data', table_schema))
        .select('payload_data.*')
    )

    # do some validation
    if valid:
        changes_df.write.mode("append").option("mergeSchema", "true").saveAsTable(target_table)
```

My issue is that I can't load the the directory using `spark.read.json()` since it will apply a superset schema to all records and I won't be able to determine which columns are `Table1` columns and which are `Table2` columns. Right now I am loading as text, extracting key JSON elements (`payload.table`), then only parsing as JSON when I have records of the same schema. This will work yet puts a lot of load on the driver node.

But I don't think filtering and iterating over the Dataframe rows is a good approach. I'd like to leverage `foreachPartition` in some way to map the validation/selection logic to executor nodes, but I am unable to due to the way the JSON schema is created using `spark.read.json()` (cant serialize to driver nodes).

How could I re-work this to be more suitable for the Spark architecture?

**UPDATE:**

I am looking to modify the data creation process so that JSON files are partitioned by table, that way I can simply `spark.read.json(table_path)` for each unique path

Comment: In your current example, the two lines are supposed to be a different schema ? because for me, it is the same.

Comment: `Table1` has columns A and B, `Table2` has columns A and C

Comment: The other issue, like I said, is that tables can add columns over time.

Comment: And you cannot define the different file with their name ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, if I could map records to files with the same table, it would be much easier. It's a dump of all tables partitioned by time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dummy file with your data.

Here is the simple code that you want to avoid:

```py
df = spark.read.json("test.json")

df.show()
+-----------------+
|          payload|
+-----------------+
|[[1, 2,], Table1]|
|[[1,, 2], Table2]|
+-----------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- colA: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- colB: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- colC: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- table: string (nullable = true)
```

The problem here is that for each new "col*", you will need to add it to your schema, and to each json line. It is automatic but it is not convenient.

You need to trick a little bit your schema for that. The type of the field `Data` is not a struct but a map:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T

schm = T.StructType(
    [
        T.StructField(
            "payload",
            T.StructType(
                [
                    T.StructField("data", T.MapType(T.StringType(), T.IntegerType())),
                    T.StructField("table", T.StringType()),
                ]
            ),
        )
    ]
)


df = spark.read.json("test.json", schema=schm)

df.show()
+--------------------+                                                          
|             payload|
+--------------------+
|[[colA -> 1, colB...|
|[[colA -> 1, colC...|
+--------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- payload: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |-- table: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hmm you and the other answer follow the same approach using the `MapType`, what if value is something other than integer? Say we add `"colD": "some_value"` which is a string? And we could extract those `colA`, `colB`, etc to their own column names?

Comment: @TomNash is it a real usecase or some theorical question ? We gave you the best answer according to your usecase and the sample data your provided. But if you're looking for the most generic solution that will fit any usecase that you do not even have, the answer - if it exists - will probably not be an efficient one.

Comment: It's real, I didn't realize I wasn't specific enough in my text description saying it can evolve and change and had to give such a detailed example (database tables of course can have columns that aren't integers). Your answer is helpful in how to re-think the problem, but I guess my solution will have to work for this specific problem.

Comment: @TomNash With a map(String, String) you can load any data but you loose the types. Knowing that types in JSON are only string, bool or numbers ... date type does not exists.

Comment: Honestly, that may work. It's what I have now with `spark.read.text` and `spark.read.json` except it's really only ints or strings. If there is a way to explode (for lack of better word) the map keys/values into different columns, then this would I think work.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm talking about the JSON - sorry it wasnt clear enough

Answer (score 1):

Your schemas aren't different. You have a `"payload"` struct with `"table"` string and `"data"` map

If you are confused how to define the schema for the `"data"`, refer [MapType](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.MapType.html)

```
data_schema = MapType(StringType(), IntegerType(), False)
payload_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("table", StringType(), False),
        StructField("data", data_schema, False),
    ]
)
schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("payload", payload_schema, False),
    ]
)
```

Comment: `data_schema` isnt always a map of string and integer, it can evolve overtime and could be integer, date, string, etc. How would that work?

Comment: I suppose that wasn't clear from the question. If that is the case, I suggest you fix the process that is creating the JSON files so that the Map does have consistent values.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clar with "The schema can change over time as columns are added upstream". Unfortunately upstream is out of my control, I'd not have any issues if I could do that. I appreciate the answer though, it definitely could be helpful.

Comment: And anyone reading that statement would assume you meant that a new `"someString": <int>` value would be added

Comment: Fair enough. Will try to provide an example of any possible column in the future.

Comment: gonna try and get the JSON file creation process changed so that all records in one subdirectory have the same schema